# Tcpclient constructor Problems C#

Tags: c#, constructor, client, tcpclient

I am trying to create a TcpClient and having problems with the constructor...

```
public class TcpClient : IDisposable
{
static void Connect(String server, String message)

{
    try
    {
        // Create a TcpClient. 
        // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
        // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
        // combination.
        Int32 port = 9000;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
```

*I get error:*

> Error 1   'TcpClient' does not contain a constructor that takes 2
>   arguments

My question:

why does this problem occurs & how to solve it?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a TcpClient when there's already such class built into the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your class is named TcpClient which is the same name given to the class in the  framework, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56.aspx). Just give your class a different name.

You can obviously also use the namespace to indicate to the compiler exactly which TcpClient class you are referring to, for example

```
new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.TcpClient(server, socket);
```